# Ionic 3 slides loop does not refresh properly when going from last to first or first to last

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, slide

I want to make a "continuous" slider in Ionic 3.

I use 3 slides and update the content on each slide action.
This works, though when swiping the last slide and looping back to the first, the content of the newly shown slide is not correct: all static data is shown, but all dynamic (bound) data is not shown. You need to initiate a new swipe action (just drag the page a tiny bit) to get the data shown.

See this plunker as an example of the issue:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YC9xiwH9hVtAmhUTO2Oc?p=preview

This is the view:

```
<ion-content padding>    
    slides:
    <ion-slides loop="true" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged($event)">
        <ion-slide>
            0 {{data[0]?.title}}
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            1 {{data[1]?.title}}
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
           2 {{data[2]?.title}}
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

This is the controller:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  appName = 'Ionic App';

    slides: Slides;

    public data: MonthViewData[] = [];

    public date = new Date(Date.now());

    monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];

    constructor() {
        this.data.push({title:'t0'});
        this.data.push({title:'t1'});
        this.data.push({title:'t2'});
    }

    slideChanged(slides: Slides) {
        this.slides = slides;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let scrollToNext = this.slides.getActiveIndex() > this.slides.getPreviousIndex();
            console.log(this.slides.getActiveIndex(), this.slides.getPreviousIndex());
            let currentSlideIndex: number = this.slides.getActiveIndex() - 1;
            if (currentSlideIndex > 2) {
                currentSlideIndex = 0;
            }
            if (currentSlideIndex < 0) {
                currentSlideIndex = 2;
            }
            let previousSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex - 1;
            let nextSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1;
            if (previousSlideIndex < 0) {
                previousSlideIndex = 2;
            }
            if (nextSlideIndex > 2) {
                nextSlideIndex = 0;
            }
            if (this.slides.getActiveIndex() == 1 && this.slides.getPreviousIndex() == 0) {
                this.date = new Date(Date.now());
            } else {
                if (scrollToNext) {
                    this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() + 1);
                } else {
                    this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() - 1);
                }
            }
            console.log('active month', this.date);
            console.log('indexes', previousSlideIndex, '->', currentSlideIndex, '->', nextSlideIndex);
            this.data[currentSlideIndex].title = this.monthNames[this.date.getMonth()] + ' ' + this.date.getFullYear();
            this.data[previousSlideIndex].title = this.monthNames[this.date.getMonth() - 1] + ' ' + this.date.getFullYear();
            this.data[nextSlideIndex].title = this.monthNames[this.date.getMonth() + 1] + ' ' + this.date.getFullYear();
        })
    }
}
```

How can I get this right?

Thanks!

Comment: Your plunker is blank...

Comment: It works for me in Chrome... though it takes quite a while to show up...

Comment: I play with your code and can not find a solution. I tried all event possible and all way to trigger change detection but no luck. I think it is really an issue of ionic slides. You should report it in github

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I will.

Comment: When you do it, please send me the link of the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you give a look in the browser inspector, you will see that the ones that don't work are the first slide after you loop from the last, or the last slide after you loop from the first (in the inverse direction), and both of them has the class `swiper-slide-duplicate`, that is, **they are duplicates**, and the ones that work are not duplicates.

Sometimes, while you are changing the slide, you can see, during a brief moment, the correct value, because the duplicate is changed with the original.

It seems `ionic` tries to duplicate the slides, but the duplication can give unexpected errors when using angular bindings and change detection, making that it doesn't work at all.

At first, (in my case, not the one in the plunker), I thought it was change detection that was not triggering in my component and tried all sorts of stuff like `ngZone.run()`, `cd.markForChanges()`, `cd.detectChanges()` and so on...

In my opinion, the current "fix" is to not use `loop` when you want dynamic change detection (the items can change), when the detection must happen inside the slide.

In my case, I disabled `loop` and use `autoPlay`, then I just call `slides.startAutoplay()` when the slide changes.

In your case it would inside `slideChanged(slides: Slides) { ... slides.startAutoplay(); }`

This won't solve your problem, tough, because in your code you want to show the next month in each slide and make it look like having infinite slides (always changing the next slide as you loop). Also, it seems you want the change to be manual (by the user).

What I advise you is to look for other approaches because I don't know when it will be solved.

There are several issues about that opened:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v1/issues/129 (it's in v1, but the problem is the same. The original issue is https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6602, created in 2016-05-21, almost 2 years ago)

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6515

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6843

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10890

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13582

(and probably more...)

Perhaps in `Ionic4` that will be solved, but I think not (at least not for now), so I advise to try another approach (instead of `ion-slides`) in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Use realIndex of slides

This is View

```
 <ion-slides loop="true" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged($event)">
   <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of items">Slide {{newval}}
       <ion-list>
         <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
           Slide {{newval}} not changing
         </ion-item>
       </ion-list> 
   </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Controller Part

```
export class HomePage {

  items: number[] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
  newval : any;
  appName = 'Ionic App';

  constructor(public navController: NavController) { }

   slideChanged(event) {
    this.newval = event.realIndex;
   }
}
```

Refer this for example

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/6o5cy8gClpBJv6iG?preview